# Linking a .lib library to a project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker

Somehow, even after going through a lot of materials, I could not understand one thing. I have a c++ library project in Visual Studio 2013. When I build it, it creates *.lib file. Now, there is another project where I need to link the .lib file. I created a folder called `lib`, dumped the .lib file in there and set the path of the `lib` folder to `Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`. Next I added the library file name `*.lib` in `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`. Now, building the project throws huge list of linker errors with message `unresolved external symbol ...`. What is that I need to do more for linking the library?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's the language your "another project" used, anyway, you should specifically set your *.lib file in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies if you didn't explicitly load it in code.

Comment: another project is also in C++. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have done what you have mentioned. Anything else is required to do?

Comment: Do I need a .dll with .lib?

Comment: @Nickal: That depends on the .lib. A .lib may contain either full functions (no DLL needed) or just the information to locate the functions inside the DLL. Since you do have a DLL, the second case applies. Compiling the second project uses the .lib, and then running it uses the DLL.

Comment: @MSalters: How to know to what category do my .lib belong among the two you have mentioned?

Comment: Actually, my second project does not even compile, it throws linker errors. M sorry for my ignorance, but I do not understand all these stuff well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nickal: You said you copied the DLL from the first project, so that produces a LIB+DLL not a standalone LIB. The second project needs that LIB to link.

Comment: Sorry, that was not .dll, that was .lib, I have edited my question. There's no .dll in the `debug` folder of the first project.

Answer (score 1):

If the both projects reside in the same solution the simplest option is to right-click of the project, go to to Properties, there go to Common Properties and in Framework and References add a reference to that library project. This will set the linker to link the .lib and adds a build dependency so the lib is always compiled before the executable.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that for another project, but the one I am trying to link is not in the same solution. And above that, I would like to know what's wrong in this case. This may help me to know about libraries better.